# Как правильно закодировать текст для отправки по AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

Никак не могу понять что нужно сделать чтобы текст типа "раз д+в+а %33три%10" нормально отсылался на сервер методом POST с помощью XMLHttpRequest.
Мои файлы:
test.php

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['sended'])) {
        exit($_POST['text']);
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="text"><br>
        <textarea id="resul"></textarea><br>
        <button id="sendText">send</button><br>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
function send () {
    let params = 'sended=1&text=' + text.value;
    let url = '';
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
            resul.value = request.responseText;
        }
    }
    request.open('POST', url);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    request.send(params);
}

sendText.addEventListener("click", send);
```

Comment: А в чем именно заключается проблема? Что значит "нормально" и как отправляется текст сейчас?

Comment: Для этого есть методы `encodeURIComponent`, `encodeUri`

Comment: текст "раз д+в+а %33три%10" превращается в "раз д в а 3три"

Comment: если вы пытаетесь отправить комментарий определенному пользователю, нужно использовать цитату `@имяПользователя`, иначе, вы, отправляете его себе и уведомление не придет, тому, кому вы пытались писать.

Comment: Читайте про кодирование и декодирование строк, при передачи его в адрес. И будет вам счастье.

Comment: @And, спасибо, encodeURIComponent помогло!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста, обращайтесь, сейчас оформлю ответ, чтобы вы его выбрали в качестве решения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого нужно воспользоваться кодирование строки, с помощью `encodeURIComponent`.

```
let params = 'sended=1&text=' + encodeURIComponent(text.value);
```